# Объясните принципы разработки авторизации в android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

У меня уже много есть вопросов по поводу авторизации в приложении андроид но информации которая получена из ответов и поисковых результатов в гугле не смогла мне объяснить некоторые вещи и я не могу понять их. Сейчас конечно все начнут говорить что я плохо гуглил и т.д., но я надеюсь что мне здесь помогут.

Во-первых я понял что для логина в приложение андроид используется две библиотеки либо retrofit либо volley, я лично думаю что буду делать на retrofit так как по нем больше информации и видосов.

Во-вторых у меня возникла идея, а что если не использовать эти все библиотеки и просто сделать перегон данных с формы в `json` и отправки на сервер по запросу?? Ну это так чисто как вариант, я просто сильно в этом пока разбираюсь))

В-третьих, я прошерстил кучу сайтов и пересмотрел кучу гайдов, и во всех случаях каждый из разработчиков создает кучу классов для обычного логина, и вот у меня вопрос нужно ли создавать кучу классов или можно сделать все как-то более компактно. Просмотрев кучу сайтов у меня так и не получилось сделать логин, даже на локальной БД.

И вот у меня есть теперь заминка при разработке авторизации в приложении, может кто-то сможет мне на очень простом языке как сделать логин при помощи `retrofit`, а то я никак не могу понять.

И так согласно первому комментарию и вопросам которые в нем были заданы: у меня есть свой сервер со своим api а именно rest api. Авторизация будет производится путем ввода пароля и лоигна которые будут вытягиваться с формы и отсылаться на сервер для проверки если все введено правильно то переход на другое активити. Уже есть база пользователей которые будут логиниться. Авторизация по популярным соц. сетям пока не берется во внимание. Передача данных на сервер пока идет в формате json но потом вроде как планируется и передавать методом post. Других способов аутентификации я думаю в ближайшем будущем не будет. Бэкендом занимаюсь не я и мне уже дали тестовый пароль и логин, а так-же кучу всяких деталей по серверной части, типа запросов и основных ошибок.

Буду очень благодарен за советы и помощь.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> буду делать на retrofit так как по нем больше информации и видосов

Не лучший ход мыслей.

> во всех случаях каждый из разработчиков создает кучу классов для обычного логина

Да, это действительно так. С тем же `Volley` или голым `OkHttp` гораздо проще сделать обычный запрос, но не проще с этим работать.

Но чаще пользуются `Retrofit`. Почему? Потому что он очень удобен.

Чуть позже, когда помимо вопросов `как написать тоже самое, но на десять строчек кода короче`, и вообще когда помимо количества строчек кода или внешней простоты реализации для вас появятся ещё какие-нибудь пункты, соответствие которым будет для вас весомым, вы поймёте, почему по `Retrofit` «куча видосов» — отчасти, из-за некоторой общей популярности, потому что работа с сетью у всех и ассоциируется с `Retrofit`, — но и популярность пришла не зря.

Да и насчёт простоты кода тоже можно поспорить — вам всего пару шагов проделать надо, и в случае сильного увеличения количества запросов, в случае усложнения этих самых запросов, количество кода будет сильно уменьшаться, и с `Volley`-ами и `OkHttp` вы устанете переписывать одно и то же везде, или костылить свои врапперы.

Пример: инициализируем

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.example.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();
```

Затем создаём интерфейс для работы с API:

```
interface MyExampleApi {

    @GET("/get-something")
    Call<MyExampleResponse> getSomething(@Query String someParameter);
}
```

Далее вам нужно десериализованный POJO для ответа от сервера написать, и всё:

```
class MyExampleResponse {
    private String topSecretInfo;

    // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

На этом «куча классов» закончилась. Удобно, разве нет? Теперь вызываем:

```
MyExampleApi api = retrofit.create(MyExampleApi.class)
api.getSomething("wow! such retrofit").enqueue(new Callback<MyExampleResponse> { /*  обработка */ });
```

Итого — у вас в коде пара строчек потрачено на логику по работе с сетью, и помимо этого ещё пара коротеньких файлов. 
Это я ещё не говорил про тестирование, DI и так далее.

Какая мораль? Если вы слабо знакомы с HTTP-протоколом, да и вообще `HTTP`, `POST` и `GET` для вас ругательства капсом — тогда не парьтесь пока что :)
В таком случае лучше изучите сначала теорию по этим вопросам. Не нужно просто брать и копировать из тырнетов огромные простыни, подменяя лишь маленький кусочек кода в серединке, который и является вашей бизнес-логикой. Вы должны сначала понимать каждую буковку, которую пишете — потом понимать цель, с которой пишется эта строчка кода и что она в итоге делает — а уже потом среди аналогов выбирать, какой же из них делает это удобнее всего.

Самое главное — не делайте ничего бездумно, не копируйте первый попавшийся код потому что он «короче», «выглядит проще» или потому что «по нему видосиков куча».

---

Если к делу — о какой конкретно авторизации идёт речь? У вас свой API, или же вы хотите встроить авторизацию через популярные сервисы вроде `VK`, `Google`, `Facebook` и всё такое прочее?

В первом случае всё зависит от протоколов и способов аутентификации. Что вы используете: `OAuth`, накостыленная передача логинов и паролей прямо в теле запроса, `Bearer`-токены?

Во втором случае обычно используются SDK этих сервисов и вручную ничего не пишут. Но иногда (как например в случае с `VK`), готовые SDK крайне убогие или не обновлялись много лет и приходится писать вручную — тогда чаще всего одними запросами вы не отделаетесь, вам придется юзера самого заставить тыкать на кнопочки, предоставленные сервисом, и скорее всего через `WebView`.

Если же всё-таки вы всё делаете вручную, и бэкенд тоже ваш, тогда логика тоже довольно проста — в случае с `Retrofit` — создаёте интерфейс (вроде написанного выше `MyExampleApi`), помещаете туда методы с нужными сигнатурами, и выстраиваете свою логику. Юзер вводит пароль, или вы как-то сами его получаете, — вместе с логином шифруете его как-нибудь, или просто так отправляете в теле запроса — делаете обычный запрос с нужными заголовками, телом или `query`, и на основе ответа от сервера решаете, залогинился юзер или нет.

---

В общих словах всё выглядит просто. Ваш вопрос довольно развёрнутый, но не содержит конкретики — мой ответ тоже развёрнут и содержит всю необходимую информацию и даже сравнение. Больше конкретики по самой авторизации я не могу на данный момент написать, потому что конкретика вопроса не позволяет.

---

**UPD**:

> Передача данных на сервер пока идет в формате json но потом вроде как планируется и передавать методом post.

А как вы планируете `json` передавать не через `POST`, в `query` как параметр при `GET`-запросе? Есть некоторые случаи такой логики, например при подписи запросов, но я сомневаюсь, что у вас это используется, а значит вам нужен именно `POST`-запрос.

Делается всё очень просто. Допустим, вам нужно отправить только логин и пароль на сервер, а в ответ придёт статус — залогинен юзер или нет. Тогда пример выше я преобразую:

Инициализация выглядит также. Интерфейс будет примерно такой:

```
interface AuthApi {

    @POST("/auth")
    Call<AuthResponse> authUser(@Body AuthRequestBody body);
}
```

Вот ваше тело запроса:

```
class AuthRequestBody {
    private String login, password;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Оно будет автоматически сериализовано в JSON с помощью GSON:

```
{ "login": "some string", "password": "some string" }
```

Допустим, вот ваш JSON-ответ от сервера:

```
{ "success": true }
```

Тогда ваш десериализованный класс может выглядеть так:

```
class AuthResponse {
    private boolean success;

    public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

Это будет сделано автоматически `GSON`-ом, т.к. вы добавили `GsonConverterFactory` в билдере при инициализации ретрофита.

Допустим, из ваших двух `EditText` по нажатию на кнопку вы получаете логин и пароль юзера:

```
String login = loginEditText.getText();
String password = passwordEditText.getText();
AuthRequestBody body = new AuthRequestBody(login, password);
```

Тело запроса сформировано. Теперь проинициализируем интерфейс для работы с API:

```
AuthApi api = retrofit.create(AuthApi.class)
Call<AuthResponse> call = api.authUser(body);
```

И теперь обрабатываем ответ:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse> {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            AuthResponse serverAnswer = response.body();

            if (serverAnswer.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                // Авторизация прошла успешно
                // можно, например, перейти на другую активити
            } else {
                // Авторизация не прошла
            }
        } else {
            // Ошибка при запросе
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<AuthResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        // Ошибка при запросе
    }
});
```

Вот, собственно, и вся логика.

Ваше тело запроса `AuthRequestBody` будет сериализовано в JSON, почитайте про то, как это работает, в частности про библиотеку GSON.

Comment: то есть я насколько понял для работы формы логина нужно создать такие классы: класс для отправки запроса на сервер и класс для приема ответа, например класс для отправки вытаскивает данные с формы и кидает на сервер, а класс ответа принимает ответ от сервера и например пишет что все ок и можно открывать новую активити?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko классы создаются для того, чтобы вам удобно было делать запросы и обрабатывать ответы. Под капотом `Retrofit` ваш JSON де/сериализует в классы и из классов, чтобы вам не парсить его вручную. Вы можете не использовать `GsonConverterFactory` и вручную работать с JSON-ом как со строкой, но это будет неудобно. А уже в десериализованной структуре (с объектом созданного вами класса) работать легче — вы сразу вызываете нужные поля или методы, которые определены заранее, и в обработке запроса вам не придётся ничего парсить. Для этого классы и используются.

Comment: ок, спасибо за очень подробный разбор моего вопроса, я приблизительно понял что и как мне нужно сделать если что, то я буду задавать уже более точные вопросы.

Comment: а вот у меня еще вопрос появился зачем нам нужен интерфейс для работы с логином?? ну то есть классы как-бы вроде понятно что и зачем нужно а вот интерфейс я так и не понял зачем нужен. и где нужно использовать обработку ответа, нужно его юзать в классе логина или создавать новый класс??

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko вы пишете интерфейс, обозначая ваш запрос, какие параметры он должен передавать, какие заголовки, по какому пути делать его и т.д. Реализацию за вас делает `Retrofit`. Итого вместо того чтобы вручную всю настройку делать, вам надо всего-то пару аннотаций навесить на метод и его входные параметры.

Comment: то есть в интерфейсе мы обращаемся из класса который отправляет запросы, который так-же  я так понял вытягивает из формы данные в json, и дальше мы получаем ответ при помощи класса с сервера, и потом мы класс-ответчик вызываем из формы входа, для открытия следующего активити, но вот что мне еще не понятно как мы поймем что ответ удовлетворительный??

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko в примере кода же я указал, там два случая где ошибки и один случай, когда ответ удовлетворительный, который вы уже и обрабатываете. А вызывать методы апи и инициализировать всё что нужно можете где хотите.

Comment: у меня почему-то не инициализируется AuthApi api = retrofit.create(AuthApi.class) и слово retrofit подчекнуто красным пишем что qualifier must be an expression я не могу понять почему так, я пихнул это все в обработку нажатия кнопку