# Помогите разобраться с библиотекой Retrofit android при авторизации в приложении

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

Я только начал работать с библиотекой Retrofit которую я использую для логина в приложении на андроид, мне уже частично растолковали часть вопросов по этой тематике. Я создал определенную структуру проекта для обеспечения нужного функционала но я все-равно не смог достичь поставленной задачи а именно войти в приложение с уже имеющимися логином и паролем. Я создал interface:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface LoginRequest
{
    @POST("/auth")
    Call<ServerResponce> authUser(@Body UserRequest body);
}
```

я создал класс для-запрос:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class UserRequest {
    @SerializedName("login")
    private String login;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public UserRequest(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

и класс-ответ:

```
class ServerResponce {
    private boolean success;

    public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

для входа я использую стандартный темплейт андроид студии экрана входа, и там я так чувствую что нужно где-то инициализировать для использования их в работе. Я так думаю что нужно его инициализировать в этой функции:

```
 private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String login = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(login)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } /*else if (!isEmailValid(login)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }*/

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            вставить наверное тут нужно.
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(login, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }
```

для работы с этим вопросом при помощи ответов приведенных в этом вопросе - [Объясните принципы разработки авторизации в android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850944/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-android). Там мне дали более чем полные ответы но все-равно я кое-что не понял, где именно нужно инициализировать данные классы и как вообще должны взаимодействовать эти классы и интерфейсы. Буду благодарен за помощь и советы.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь разобраться минимум в двух, а может даже и в трех новых для вас вещах сразу. Начните по одному. Напишите приложение без UI, которое будет с помощью Retrofit делать что вам надо. Как только заработает, можете приступать к прикручиванию UI сверху.

Comment: Можно начать с голого Retrofit (без GSON), потом GSON прикрутить, потом UI.

Comment: что значит на голом?? мы будем каким-то образом перекидывать данные из полей для ввода на сервер и получать ответы??? на данный момент я как-бы над ui почти не работал, просто не могу понять как это будет реализовываться, примеров просмотрел кучу, но все равно не дошло.

Comment: "голый", это значит когда вам всегда приходит `Call<ResponseBody>` и никаких конвертеров. Про UI, вернее его отсутствие: ничего никуда не надо перекидывать, определите константы в коде и работайте с ними.