# Работа с библиотекой retrofit android для создания авторизации в приложении

Tags: android, post, клиент-сервер, retrofit

Вот уже какой раз я задаю вопрос связанный с библиотекой retofit android которую я использую для создания экрана авторизации в своем приложении. Мне уже очень много чего рассказали и посоветовали, много чего я прочитал в интернете. В итоге на данный момент я создал голое приложение для работы с библиотекой retofit которое конвертирует введенный текст в поля формы в json и потом после нажатия на кнопку submit выводится переконвертированная информация в textview. Для работы с данным вопросом я использовал свои предыдущие вопросы: [Помогите разобраться с библиотекой Retrofit android при авторизации в приложении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852176/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-retrofit-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

[Объясните принципы разработки авторизации в android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850944/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-android)

Там очень много дельных советов, после которых я разбил свою задачу на несколько подзадач, а именно я пока создал (мне кажется что там все работает правильно) просто структуру проекта для конвертирования данных в json, но сервер на который я вроде как отправляю запросы не мой http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ и вероятнее всего просто использовался в примере для эмуляции запросов. 
Вот мои классы для работы: 
1.

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

2.

```
import com.example.developer_4.test_log.APIService;

public class ApiUtils {
    private ApiUtils() {}

    public static APIService getAPIService() {

        return RetrofitClient.getClient().create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

3.

```
import com.example.developer_4.test_log.data.model.model.LoginRequest;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIService {
    @POST("/posts")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    //Call<ServerResponce> authUser(@Body LoginRequest body);
    Call<LoginRequest> savePost(@Field("login") String login, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

4.

```
    public class LoginRequest {

    @SerializedName("login")
    @Expose
    private String login;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoginRequest{" +
                "login ='" + login + '\'' +
                ", password =" + password + '}';
    }
}
```

и вот теперь я хочу отправить запрос на нужный мне сервер но у меня не получается, вроде и ошибки нету и программа не слетает но все равно не могу понять в чем проблема.То есть я вроде как создал пока-что конвертер но нужно отправить на нужный сервер запрос и если кто знает как мне этот вопрос растолковать то я ему буду очень признателен.

Comment: вам нужно подправить вопрос) Отправка запроса на сервер не связана с ретрофитом. Приведите код, который вы используете для отправки на сервер, а мы поможем вам его отладить=)

Comment: я понимаю что мой вопрос не сильно правильно задан )) для отправки на сервер я так думал что мы используем метод post но теперь я в этом не сильно уверен, по факту я не смог создать кусок кода который отвечает за отправку данных на сервер, у меня мой сериализованный запрос пока-что выводится с textview а на сервер я не знаю пока как отправлять, я могу отредактировать вопрос так как нужно но того что вы просите у меня походу нету.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не совсем ответ на ваш вопрос, но хорошая подсказка как понять что идет не так.

У `Retrofit` есть вспомогательный модуль `logging-interceptor`. Подключается так:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
```

Используется так, только для debug сборок (Kotlin):

```
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    builder.addInterceptor(logging)
}
val okHttpClient = builder.build()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
     .client(okHttpClient)
     .build()
return retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
```

Как результат, в LogCat увидите все ваши запросы в сыром виде и ответы сервера тоже.

Надеюсь, это поможет разобраться что же и почему не работает так как нужно.

Comment: а для java такое можно тоже сделать??? и куда вставлять этот фрагмент кода? в onCreate?

Comment: да можно я нашел как)))))

Answer (score 0):

Приведу вам простой код, который использую сам для риложения без авторизации (тяну расписание с сайта в открытом доступе).

**RequestWrapper** - класс, обертка запросов.

```
import okhttp3.Call
import okhttp3.Callback
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.IOException

class RequestWrapper(private val apiClient: okhttp3.OkHttpClient, private var apiCall: Call?) {

    fun enqueue(
            request: Request,
            requestCallback: RequestCallback) {

        val modifiedApiClient = apiClient
                .newBuilder()
                .build()

        apiCall = modifiedApiClient.newCall(request.newBuilder().build())

        apiCall!!.enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                requestCallback.onFailure(call, e)
            }

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response) {
                var responseBody: String? = null
                try {
                    responseBody = response.body()!!.string()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                requestCallback.onResponse(call, response, responseBody)
            }
        })
    }


    interface RequestCallback {
        fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException)

        fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response, bodyString: String?)
    }
}
```

**RequestConfig** - конфиг для работы с сервером.

```
class RequestConfig {
    companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "http://ruz2.spbstu.ru/api/v1/ruz/"
        const val FACULTIES = "faculties/"
    }
}
```

**NetworkFragment** - родительский фрагмент для всех фрагментов, которые работают с сервером (апи):

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Message
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.widget.Toast
import argument.twins.com.polykekschedule.Application.Companion.apiCall
import argument.twins.com.polykekschedule.Application.Companion.apiClient
import argument.twins.com.polykekschedule.models.Faculties
import argument.twins.com.polykekschedule.requests.RequestConfig.Companion.BASE_URL
import argument.twins.com.polykekschedule.requests.RequestConfig.Companion.FACULTIES
import argument.twins.com.polykekschedule.requests.RequestWrapper
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import okhttp3.Call
import okhttp3.HttpUrl
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.IOException


open class NetworkFragment : Fragment() {
    private val SCHOOLS: String = "schools"
    private var viewModel: ScheduleViewModel ?= null
    private lateinit var mHandler: Handler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ScheduleViewModel::class.java)
        mHandler = Handler()
    }

    protected fun getSchoolsList(){
        val endPointFaculties = BASE_URL + FACULTIES
        getRequest(endPointFaculties, SCHOOLS)
    }

    private fun getRequest(url: String, type: String, vararg urlParts: String) {
        val builder = HttpUrl.parse(url)!!.newBuilder()
        for(part in urlParts)
            builder.addPathSegment(part)


        val requestBuilder = Request.Builder()
                .url(builder.build())
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .get()

        val request = requestBuilder.build()

        RequestWrapper(apiClient, apiCall)
                .enqueue(request, object : RequestWrapper.RequestCallback {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response, bodyString: String?) {
                        if (response.code() == 204 || bodyString == null || !response.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Ошибка сервера", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            return
                        }

                        try {
                            val jsonObject = JSONObject(bodyString)
                            val gson = getBuiltGsonInstance()

                            when(type){
                                SCHOOLS -> {
                                    val facultiesObj = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Faculties::class.java)
                                    viewModel?.schools = facultiesObj.faculties
                                }
                            }

                            mHandler.post { updateView() }

                        } catch (e: JSONException) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Ошибка сервера # 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Ошибка сети", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                })
    }

    fun getBuiltGsonInstance(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder()
                .serializeNulls()
                .create()
    }

    open fun updateView(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Обновление по-умолчанию", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

для отправки запросов я использую библиотеку okhttp3 и библиотеку для парсинга json объектов:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

Вы можете посмотреть, как устроен мой простой пример, и на его основа начать отправлять простые запросы. Но для решения ваших будущих проблем такого класса не достаточно. Так как вы реализуете авторизацию, вам придется реализовать и работу с токенами. Не может пользователь авторизоваться 1 раз, а потом никак не напоминать о себе. Обычно, после авторизации пользователю дается 2 токена. 1 вечный (кажется наз-ся access token, почти вечный), другой скажем на час (refresh token). Если спустя час, пользователь сделает запрос,а к этому времени refresh токен стух), то сначала необходимо запросить у сервера обновление этого токена, и только после этого делать запрос за получением данных (т.е. это как минимум очередь из двух запросов). Вам следуете почитать об этом хорошенько. В общем-то в авторизации нет ничего сложного, но реализовать ее граммотно - это дело не простое. Удачи.

Comment: Автор просил Retrofit :)

Comment: а что, оно умеет запросы на северы слать?)

Comment: Умеет :) `Retrofit: A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java`, http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: ооо.. ну тогда конечно мой вариант абсолютно костыльный в случае использования retrofit. Ищите, как сделать запрос средствами ретрофита =)

Comment: Ваш вариант вполне рабочий, хоть и не без изьянов, только на Retrofit было бы намного меньше кода.