# Не подгружает данные с Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

есть небольшая проблемма:
В активити создается карта, юзер ставит маркер и эти координаты заносятся в локальную базу данных и переходим на другую активити (все работало, пока не начал внеднять ретрофит). Аналогичный код - работал в другом проекте, а здесь даже не попадает на вызов метода добавления в БД, но теоретически должно работать. Думаю возможно проблема в потоками. Подскажите пожалуйста

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private final static int LAYOUT_NAME = R.layout.activity_maps;
    private final static int TYPE_THEME = R.style.AppTheme;
    private final static int TITLE = R.string.map;

    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private IMyWeather iMyWeather;
    Context context = this;

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTitle(TITLE);
    setTheme(TYPE_THEME);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(LAYOUT_NAME);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

private void init(){
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    iMyWeather = retrofit.create(IMyWeather.class);
    PlacesModel placesModel = new PlacesModel(context);
    map.setOnMapClickListener((LatLng latLng) -> {
        map.clear();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Add to places?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                    compositeDisposable.add(iMyWeather.getAPI(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude,
                            "metric", "9d8ba174a36709c36aa8a6c784731c28")
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new Consumer<APIWeather>() {
                                @Override
                                public void accept(APIWeather apiWeather) throws Exception {
                                    placesModel.AddPlace(apiWeather);
                                }
                            }));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlacesActivity.class);
                    compositeDisposable.clear();
                    startActivity(intent);
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> map.clear())
                .show();
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    if (map!=null){ init(); }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

}
```

Огромное спасибо заранее!)

Comment: Поможет понять, если с Retrofit все Ок или нет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852517/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-retrofit-android-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/852643#852643

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы делаете `compositeDisposable.clear();` по нажатию на кнопку "Yes"? У вас запрос не успевает выполнится, вы уже `clear` вызываете. Перенесите вызов                     `compositeDisposable.clear();`
  в другое место