# Данные с сервера при помощи Retrofit не получаются

Tags: android, retrofit

Имеется следующий код:

```
    private static final String Tag = "DataUtil";

    static List<Film> generateFilms(){
        Log.i(Tag, "In generate films");
        List  <Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
        String BaseUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=956febbc&";
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        APIService apiService  = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        final Call<List<Film>> filmsCall = apiService.getFilms();
        filmsCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Film>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Film>> call, Response<List<Film>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.i(Tag, response.body().get(0).getTitle());
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(Tag, "Response code: "+response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Film>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: "+t);
            }
        });

        return films;
    }
```

Его задача - получить данные с [сайта](http://www.omdbapi.com/). Вот интерфейс, который содержит метод получения данных ( в данном случае получаю фильм Batman):

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("t=batman")
    Call<List<Film>> getFilms();

}
```

Однако почему-то строка `Log.i(Tag, response.body().get(0).getTitle());` не добавляется в логгер => данные не приходят. Однако строки `Log.i(Tag, "Response code: "+response.code());` и `Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: "+t)` тоже не добавляются => ошибок не возникает. В чем проблема?

Comment: Даже если запрос составлен правильно (в плане ретрофита), то на запрос `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=956febbc&t=batman` он выдал не список, а один объект

Comment: @woesss если убрать везде `<List<Film>>`, оставить только <Film> - ситуация та же.

Comment: А `response.body().get(0).getTitle()` на `response.body().getTitle()` Вы при этом заменили? И не может быть, чтобы в логах у Вас не было ошибок при таком раскладе.

Comment: да, этот случай тоже заменил

Comment: Добавьте интерцептор и посмотрите что происходит. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852643/184031

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, добавил. В logcat появилась следующая строка: `I/: Error: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to www.omdbapi.com not permitted by network security policy`

Comment: Новая политика безопасности на en-SO есть ответы: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41650965