# Код ошибки 403 retrofit

Tags: android, json

Подскажите кто знает! Отправляю запрос для получения ответа и получаю ошибку 403.
Вот MainActivity

```
ttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    // Add Interceptor to HttpClient
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    // Init retrofit object
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://...")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client) // Set HttpClient to be used by Retrofit
            .build();
    jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

    getPosts();
}

private void getPosts() {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("my_id", "0000");
    Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts(parameters);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                return;
            }

            List<Post> posts = response.body();

            for (Post post : posts) {
                String content = "";
                content += "ID: " + post.getId() + "\n";
                content += "User ID: " + post.getUserId() + "\n";
                content += "Title: " + post.getTitle() + "\n";
                content += "Text: " + post.getText() + "\n\n";

                textViewResult.append(content);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
            textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
        
        }
    });
}
```

Вот интерфейс:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {
@GET("get_personnel")
@Headers({"Signature: reserve", "Content-Type: text/x-json"})
Call<List<Post>> getPosts(@QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters);
```

}
Вот post:

```
private int userId;

private Integer id;

private String title;


@SerializedName("header")
private String text;

public Post(String title, String text) {
    this.title = title;
    this.text = text;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}
```

}

Comment: проверить существование и права доступа к `baseUrl("http://...")`. Как вариант, использовать https

Comment: Если https, то вообще нет подключения.

Comment: Ошибка доступа 403 происходит, когда веб-страница (или другой ресурс), которую вы пытаетесь открыть в веб-браузере, является ресурсом, к которому у вас ограничен доступ. может еще надо какой-то токен передавать? может там не get а post запрос?

Comment: Та и post и get менял. А когда меняю на https то получаю другую ошибку : JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $. Может я заголовки не правильно передаю?

Comment: Зачем гадать, посмотрите логи сетевого обмена, все ясно станет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852643/184031