# Как правильно получить ответ от сервера?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Есть условие: отпраить запрос на сервер

```
{
    "user_id":"a40d38a959f1ca65"
}
```

включая заголовки:

```
X-Signature: reserved
Content-Type: text/x-json
```

И должен получить ответ в таком формате:

```
 {
   "person":[
      {
         "user_number":000,
         "name":"Коля",
         "sec_name":"Николай",
         "mid_name":"",
         "code":1111
      },
     "person":[
      {
         "user_number":111,
         "name":"Вася",
         "sec_name":"Василий",
         "mid_name":"",
         "code":1223
      },
   ],
   "success":true
}
```

Я это делаю так:
Интерфейс

```
    @Headers({"X-Signature: reserved","Content-Type: text/x-json"})
@GET("get_users/")
Call<List<Post>> getmodels( @QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters);
```

Post

```
@SerializedName("personnel")
@Expose
private List<Personnel> personnel = null;
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;

public List<Personnel> getPersonnel() {
    return personnel;
}

public void setPersonnel(List<Personnel> personnel) {
    this.personnel = personnel;
}

public Boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}
```

public class Personnel {

```
@SerializedName("personnel_number")
@Expose
private Integer personnelNumber;
@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String lastName;
@SerializedName("middle_name")
@Expose
private String middleName;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;

public Integer getPersonnelNumber() {
    return personnelNumber;
}

public void setPersonnelNumber(Integer personnelNumber) {
    this.personnelNumber = personnelNumber;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}
}

Клиент

```
    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://...")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

    String id_user = "device_id: a40d38a959f1ca65";
    Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getmodels(id_user);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
            List<Post>data = response.body();
          
            textViewResult.append("CODE: " + data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

И я получаю всегда null, что нужно изменить, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Мне непонятно почему вы считаете что входной параметр, который вы определили, соответствует типу `text/x-json`. Из условия так же не понятно почему GET запрос. А вообще понять, откуда и куда копать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852643/184031

Comment: И тот пример ответа не является валидным JSON, так что разберитесь с заданием сначала. И совет: не пишите сразу структуры данных. Получите для начала нужный ответ в виде обычной строки, потом можно и структуры сверху прикрутить.