# При получении данных Json с помощью Retorfit возникает NullPointerException

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

```
class ApiDataSourceIMPL(private val exchangeRateDataSource: ExchangeRateDataSource, private val currencyDataSource: CurrencyDataSource):
    ApiDataSource {

    override fun startMigration (context: Context) {

        val call = ApiClient.instance?.api?.loadExchangeRateApi()
        call?.enqueue(object: Callback<ExchangeRateResponseModel> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel>,
                response: Response<ExchangeRateResponseModel>
            ) {

Log.d("ApiDataSource", "onResponse status: ${response.code()}")

                // создаём список
                var loadExchangeRate: ExchangeRateResponseModel? = null
                // очищаем массив
              //  loadExchangeRate?.clear()
                // получаем данные с сервера
                loadExchangeRate = (response.body() as ExchangeRateResponseModel?)!!


                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(1,"AUD", loadExchangeRate.rates?.AUD.toString()))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(2,"EUR", loadExchangeRate.rates?.EUR.toString()))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(3,"JPY", loadExchangeRate.rates?.JPY.toString()))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(4,"MDL", loadExchangeRate.rates?.MDL.toString()))
                exchangeRateDataSource.insert(ExchangeRateModel(5,"RUB", loadExchangeRate.rates?.RUB.toString()))



                Toast.makeText(context, "ЗАГРУЗКА", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ExchangeRateResponseModel/*ArrayList<ExchangeRateApiModel>*/>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ОШИБКА! ВКЛЮЧИТЕ ИНТЕРНЕТ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.e("ApiDataSource", "onFailure", t)
            }
        })

    }

}
```

В строке `loadExchangeRate = (response.body() as ExchangeRateResponseModel?)!!` возникает ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sem.exchangerate, PID: 30701
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sem.exchangerate.data.dataSourceIMPL.ApiDataSourceIMPL$startMigration$1.onResponse(ApiDataSourceIMPL.kt:34)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$retrofit2-DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

модели:

ExchangeRateResponseModel:

```
data class ExchangeRateResponseModel (
    @SerializedName("rates") @Expose
    val rates: ExchangeRateApiModel? = null
)
```

ExchangeRateApiModel:

```
data class ExchangeRateApiModel (

    @SerializedName("AUD") @Expose
    val AUD: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("EUR") @Expose
    val EUR: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("JPY") @Expose
    val JPY: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("MDL") @Expose
    val MDL: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("RUB") @Expose
    val RUB: Double? = null

)
```

ExchangeRateModel:

```
@Entity(tableName = "exchange_rate_table")
class ExchangeRateModel(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "exchange")
    val exchange:String
)
```

---

До этого в `ExchangeRateModel` был такой код:

```
@Entity(tableName = "exchange_rate_table")
class ExchangeRateModel(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "AUD")
    val AUD: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "EUR")
    val EUR: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "JPY")
    val JPY: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "MDL")
    val MDL: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "RUB")
    val RUB: String

)
```

После того, как я его поменял на то, что сейчас (и, соответственно, изменил заполнение таблицы в `ApiDataSourceIMPL`), начала вылетать ошибка

Comment: а вы базу после изменений чистили/пересоздавали?

Comment: `Log.d("ApiDataSource", "onResponse status: ${response.code()}")` - добавьте это в начало колбека `onResponse()` и смотрите в логах какой у вас код ответа. Код ответа в принципе нужно проверять всегда и если он не успешный, то тело запроса трогать нельзя. И на время разработки неплохо бы добавить [логирующий интерсептор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852643/11515) - так вы будете видеть в логах запросы/ответы и сможете оценить их правильность.

Comment: @Andrew, базу данных пересоздал - не помогло

Comment: @woesss, `Log.d("ApiDataSource", "onResponse status: ${response.code()}")` вставил (в коде вопроса добавил эту строку, на случай, если вставил не туда), в `Logcat` в разделе `Verbose` выходил сообщение `D/ApiDataSource: onResponse status: 401`

Comment: Ну а теперь смотрим что означает этот код: [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#401) и обращаемся к документации API сервера с вопросом как это сделать.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо!